# How can i custom filter for 302 Status Code in spring mvc java and response.redirect to custom page?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, filter

Hi all  I want to create RedirectionFilter at java spring. The main purpose is when status code 302 is detected then  send  redirect and replacing the response content by custom text content. The first problem is don't know how to catch the response code 302. This is my current thinking .

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) (request);
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String redirectURL="www.google.com";
if(statuscode == 302 ){
httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
}
```

Something like that. I have out of ideas. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HandlerInterceptorAdapter  to get the response after each call and can validate the response code and do necessary things

```
@Component
public class TestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, java.lang.Object object) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("test");
    return true;
}
@Override
public void afterCompletion(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response, java.lang.Object handler, @org.springframework.lang.Nullable java.lang.Exception ex) throws java.lang.Exception {
    if(response.getStatus()==302){
        // your code
    }
}
}
```

After creating a interceptor need to register it in InterceptorRegistry

```
@Component
public class InterceptorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private TestInterceptor testInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(testInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Once triggering a request, the control will come to interceptor first.

Restcontroller sample

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class Restcontroller {

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView redirectWithUsingRedirectPrefix(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("attribute", "redirectWithRedirectPrefix");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/redirectedUrl", model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the information can u provide more info? Don't i need to do with Filter?Thanks.

Comment: I tried getStatus method before but it showing error of The method getStatus() is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse.

Comment: Please try with the above updated code and let me know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: any updates, is this solution addressed your problem?